# Сохранение данных

Tags: установка, ubuntu

При установке хотел сохранить диск D, устанавливал впервые, когда делал разметку задал точку диска D как /дом и тип Ext4. Теперь там ничего нет, данные утеряны?

Answer (score 1):

Для Linux есть замечательная утилита, которая не раз меня спасала. Зовется testdisk, в ее составе есть также Photoreg. Находится в стандартных дистрибутивных пакетах Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Запускается из терминала, дальше интуитивно понятно...

Успехов желаю.

P.S. Диск с именем "D" вряд ли имел файловую систему отличную от NTFS. Данные утеряны железобетонно...

Answer (score 0):

если на D до этого была ФС отличная от Ext4 то данные скорее всего уже не восстановить (хотя я не специалист по восстановлению данных, возможно есть способы), если была Ext4 и вы не ставили галочку форматировать, то данные должны были сохраниться.